# Popup use scrollbar of window

Tags: javascript, css, scrollbar

I'm trying to create a popup which uses window scrollbars not the div ones. Something like what is on http://pinterest.com. How to achieve this effect? All my tries are unsuccessful, scrollbars appear on div. Window scollbars scroll the body content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you open popup window, you should remember current window scrollLeft/scrollTop positions somewhere, then apply `overflow:hidden`, `height/width:100%` to html and body, which will prevent page scrolling.

Create overlay `div` with `position:absolute`, `z-index:9999`, `left/top:0`, `height/width:100%`, `overflow:auto`, and append it to body - it will be scrollable container of your popup.

Inside of this container create `div` with `position:absolute` and `left/top` values, calculated in js to center it if necessary.

After you close popup, restore `overflow`, `height/width` styles for html/body, and apply scrollLeft/scrollTop values that were saved before opening popup.

Comment: This doesn't work entirely. When I implemented it, I could scroll to a point, but if my browser was resized to a smaller size, it wouldn't account for it.

Comment: Please clarify your question as it's not clear for me. Overlay is set to `height/width:100%`, so it will be resized automatically when browser window is resized. `oveflow:auto` style allows scrolling internal content if it's bigger than overlay. You should handle `window.resize` event to center your modal window, but make sure that top/left >= 0, otherwise you won't be able to scroll to these left/top values.

Comment: @Cereal something wrong with your styles. You shouldn't use `position:fixed`, as it makes element not scrollable. Look at this basic [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ubPF3/) which contains simpliest CSS/JS/HTML.

Comment: The container width does not change on browser resize like your example, despite copying it exactly. I don't understand why.

As you can see here: http://codepen.io/ThirdSign/live/qkEge The modal does not react to resize at all, and still does not scroll when overflowing.

I've looked through the CSS applied when the modal is open, and I see nothing influencing the left, top proerties of the modal.

Comment: @Cereal try to not use this site for this purpose - its behavior is weird. When I tried to look at iframe body in firebug, it shows me that iframe body height/width is far bigger than browser size. That's why you can't scroll it. Better to test on local HTML file or, at least, jsFiddle.

Comment: Loading into jsfiddle allows the movement on resize correctly, but there's still no scrolling. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/ubPF3/1/

Comment: @Cereal you're using too many external js and css which add their own behavior. To make scrollbar visible, you should add `no-scroll` class **both to body and html**, also `no-scroll` class should use `width/height:100%`. After this modal will be scrollable, but you won't see scrollbars as they are hidden by `bootstrap-combined.min.css`, to see scrollbar you should set body padding to 0. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ubPF3/2/)

Comment: I solved it on my own. I had to set the height of the modal container to 100%. Thanks!