# Moving a modal's scrollbar to the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have a modal that is longer than the screen height on some monitors. To remedy this, allow the modal to overflow on the y-axis. This creates a scrollbar inside the modal that lets the user scroll up and down the content.

My question is: How do I move that scrollbar to appear as the full page's scrollbar instead of the modal's?

Current CSS:

```
#scheduleModal {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 80%;

}
.no-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

and javascript, which causes the background to stop moving:

```
$('.modal-open-btn').on('click', function() {
  $('body').addClass('no-scroll');
});
```

and html is in the form:

```
<div aria-hidden='true' aria-labelledby='scheduleModalLabel' class='modal hide fade text-center' id='scheduleModal' role='dialog'>
  <div class='modal-header'>
    ...
  </div>
  <div class='modal-body'>
    ...
  </div>
  <div class='modal-footer'>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Popup use scrollbar of window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635362/popup-use-scrollbar-of-window)